# Right now Google only shows my site sometimes, how do I get consistently ranked for a keyword?

Tags: seo, google-search, google-index

I need help for a particular key word.  My site sometimes will appear on the Google search results and sometimes on the other pages.

When I used a VPN, I didn't see any problems with the search results.  The position of that word is fixed.

why is my site ranked in Google results for particular keyword only some of the time? Is there any way to make it rank more consistently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google search results vary drastically depending on

- Type of device used
- Search history
- Logged in to a Google Account while searching
- GPS Location
- Type of browser
- Google takes into account many factors to give the user the most relevant result based on the data the have on them.

Comment: Google also just randomly changes the results.   It does so to experiment with different sites in different positions.   I think it also does so just to mix things up sometimes.